# CSS select rowgroup elements but not the non-rowgroup elements

Tags: html, css

I have some tables like this:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="2">Rowgroup</th>
    <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
```

I want a general CSS rule to catch all the scope="row" elements when part of a rowgroup but not when they aren't part of a rowgroup like this:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Row 1</th>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Row 2</th>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
```

My goal is to have all my TH's one color, except when part of a rowgroup. I tried this but it only catches the first one:

```
th[scope="rowgroup"] th { color: blue; }
```

I don't care about browser compatibility and using many rules is fine, I just want to avoid using id or class selectors or javascript if possible.

Comment: Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/H4Hy9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that with simply CSS.

The problem is that CSS does not support going "up", only going "down". In your first example, it would be impossible to reach the `th` located in the second `tr`, they are "cousins" with the `th scope="rowgroup"` element, so you would have to go up first and then go down.

It is easy to solve with Javascript/jQuery, or if you can add a class on the `tr` that contains the `th scope="rowgroup"` in your HTML.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of =(

Answer (score -1):

Juste use as css code:

```
th {color:blue;}
th[scope="rowgroup"] { color: red; }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H4Hy9/1/